# XSLT: why does <for-each> not iterate twice

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

For the given XSL and XML I am getting only one row of output. Since the `for-each` has two sequences, I expect 2 lines of output?
What am I missing?

XSL used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="pat" as="item()*">
        <xsl:sequence select="/myroot[1]/mychild[1]/test[1]/@testing"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="/myroot[1]/mychild[2]/comment[1]"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="$pat">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". instance of element()">
                <xsl:text>        Node: </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>Atomic value: </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<myroot >
    <mychild id="123">
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
        <test hello="world" testing="removed" brackets="angled" question="answers"/>
        <comment>This is a comment</comment>
    </mychild>         
    <mychild id="789">
        <fruit>orange</fruit>
        <test brackets="round" hello="greeting">
            <number>111</number>
        </test>
        <!-- this is a test comment -->
        <dates>
            <modified>123</modified>
            <created>880</created>
            <accessed>44</accessed>
        </dates>
    </mychild>         
    <mychild id="456">
        <fruit>banana</fruit>
        <comment>This will be removed</comment>
    </mychild>
</myroot>
```

The output is shown below. All I received is only one line.
Why the 2nd sequence did not display anything?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Atomic value: removed

I expected it to display something like given below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Atomic value: removed
Node : This is a comment

Comment: Your question was missing a critical tag. Because you are using `<xsl:sequence>` and `instance of` I added the XSLT-2.0 tag. Now it's a whole new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there's only one node in the selected sequence:

1. `/myroot[1]/mychild[1]/test[1]/@testing` selects 1 node
2. `/myroot[1]/mychild[2]/comment[1]` selects 0 nodes

For #2, if you wish to select the first ***comment*** node child of the second `mychild` element rather than the first `comment` ***element*** (which doesn't exist as a child of the second `mychild` element), then change

```
    <xsl:sequence select="/myroot[1]/mychild[2]/comment[1]"/>
```

to

```
    <xsl:sequence select="/myroot[1]/mychild[2]/comment()[1]"/>
```

Comment: Also of course if $node is a comment node then `$node instance of element()` will be false.

Comment: @MichaelKay: True, but that condition never comes into play for a comment node because the faulty XPath #2 selects no comment nodes.  (There's still a `xsl:otherwise`  that would report a second iteration *if* it existed.)